# Given an array with n elements and an integer k. Divide the array into subarrays, each of them containing k ekements

Tags: arrays, sub-array

For example:

Input: arr[]={1, 32, 5, 6, 9, 3} and k=2

The subarrays will have elements
{132}, {56}, {93}.

Now sort these subarrays as {56}, {93}, {132}. Merge these subarrays together and display them as the elements of original array in sorted order as

Final output: arr[]={5, 6, 9, 3, 1, 32}

Comment: Please give a complete C++ solution ASAP.This question has been asked many times in Informatica interview and I am having my Informatica interview within 15 days.I could solve upto the sorting part and then I am getting stuck.Please provide a C++ solution

Comment: Someone Pls try to provide a solution ASAP(only C++)

Answer (score 3):

```
void SortByGroup(vector<int>& v, int k)
{
    int n = v.size();
    int index;
    string str = " ";
    vector<pair<int, int> > arr;    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + k)
    {   
        str = " ";
        for (int j = i ; j < i+ k ; j++) 
        {
            str += to_string(v[j]);     //convert k number into string 
        }   
        arr.push_back(make_pair(atoi(str.c_str()), i)); //push string into other vector

    }
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end()); // Sorting of array
    vector<int> res;

    for (int i = 0; i < (n / k); i++) { 
        int index = arr[i].second; //starting index of contcanate string , run k time from index to get actual no
        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
        {
            res.push_back(v[index++]); 
        }   
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << res[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{       
    int k =2;
    vector<int> vec{ 1, 32, 5, 6, 9, 3 };
    SortByGroup(vec,k);
    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: Please provide short description of what you have done in that code and how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> First divide the array into (n+k-1)/k segment and insert the value into a vector.
>   convert each segment values into a string and create a user define a data type like structure that contains a string, string length and original index of the segment. Sorting the structure based on string length in lexicographical order.
>   now you have sorted structure print the segments one by one according to the structure.

code implementation

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct con
{
    string str;
    int len;
    int ind;
};
bool comp(con a,con b)
{
    if(a.len<=b.len)
    {
        if(a.len==b.len)
        return a.str<b.str;
        return true;
    }
    //return true;
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr[i];
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        int s=n/k;
        if(n%k!=0)
        s=s+1;
        vector<int>b[s];
        int m=-1;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(i%k==0)
            m++;
            b[m].push_back(arr[i]);
        }
        con st[s];
        for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
        {
            string str="";
            for(int j=0;j<b[i].size();j++)
            {
                str+=to_string(b[i][j]);
            }
            st[i].str=str;
            st[i].len=str.length();
            st[i].ind=i;
        }
        sort(st,st+s,comp);
        for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
        {
            m=st[i].ind;
            for(int j=0;j<b[m].size();j++)
            cout<<b[m][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it